# Remove hash from url

Tags: jquery

I'm using this example http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/.
I've managed to implement it but when my page is scrolling to a particular div the id of my div is added to the url i.e http://www.example.com/#footer.
This thing does not happen in the demo page.
What have i missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to run the preventDefault() to stop the browser following the link at the end of your javascript:

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/